# Rails Two players card game

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket

I need to implement a card game between two players. A player clicks "bet" button, then a game appears in queue list and another player clicks "join" button, and then the game starts. Technologies I use include Rails 4, websocket-rails, jQuery. What I'm confused about is how to show each player their own cards and to not show the opponent's cards on the board. What technique is being used for this purpose? I think I should use internal websocket-rails' `connection_store` method to store players' cards, but I'm not sure how to work with it later in game and how to store each player's cards in variables

Has anybody here have this kind of experience with websocket-rails? Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you could create uniq `chanel` for each user and send specific data to this chanel (like data about user cards). Also you could create second broadcast chanel for concrete game, when just joined users could send messages to it, and there you could put data accessible for all users in game. About connection_store you could look [DataStore](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/wiki/Using-the-DataStore).

About dealing cards, you should have some pack of cards (36 cards) and when game is started you can randomly select few cards (depends on game) for each user, also each user connected to game has his own unique chanel to which you can put these cards, in broadcasting chanel you can put some game data (like how many players, who should run first, etc.) if user makes some action you can trigger it and send data to server (like put card on the table) then you send to broadcast chanel this public action, and give ability for other user do someting else. Jquery on one client shouldn't know about which cards other client has. All actions between user go through the server.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I still don't understand how channels will help me to deal cards to logged in user participating in the game. I need something like `if user1 deal cards1 else if user2 deal cards 2` in jquery, but jquery doesn't know who currently logged in user is

Comment: add something about dealing cards